# Finished with error: Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, release, androidx

When I try to build a release version of my flutter app this error occurs.
I now that there are many similar questions on StackOverflow, but I've tried a lot of things to solve it, and none of them helped.

Many people said that this is because of the conflict between one of the firebase plugins (I don't remember which one exactly) which migrated to AndroidX and my app which obviously didn't. So I tried to migrate, but when I press Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX... this occurs:

> You need to have compileSdk set to at least 28 in your module build.gradle to migrate to AndroidX

But I have 29 compileSdk, so then I was looking how to solve this problem, I was advised to go to android module and then migrate. Well it worked, I guess, but the main problem still wasn't solved.
Then I've found an issue on git, where people said to run `flutter clean`, this didn't help.

Dependencies from android/build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Dependencies from android/app/build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.2.0-beta01"
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Dependencies from pubspec.yaml:

```
    http: ^0.12.0+2
    shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
    url_launcher: ^5.1.3
    intent: ^1.1.0
    firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
    firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
    firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
    cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5
    google_sign_in: ^4.0.7
    flutter_facebook_login: ^1.1.1
    video_player: ^0.10.2+5
```

Comment: What version of firebase and google services are you using in your build.gradle?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Open your flutter app folder and go to `android\app\build.gradle` and add `aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false }` above your `defaultConfig {}`.
Check an example below

```
aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false }
 defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.test.test"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check your sdk and dependecies version on File -> project structure -> modules or dependencies tab... and check that everything is up to date