# how to fix the below error after upgrading my flutter

Tags: flutter

/C:/Users/Funmi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/isolate_bloc-1.0.4/lib/src/common/isolate/platform_channel/isolated_platform_channel_middleware.dart:29:25: Error: The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BinaryMessenger'.

- 'BinaryMessenger' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/binary_messenger.dart' ('/C:/Users/Funmi/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/binary_messenger.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setMockMessageHandler'.
  platformMessenger.setMockMessageHandler(channel, (message) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Funmi\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1052
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Funmi\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           40.2s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

**[Finished with error: Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58597559/finished-with-error-gradle-task-assemblerelease-failed-with-exit-code-1)**

**check this website and apply it by order some values end of the implementation or classpath could be old , search and change compared to depracated.**